# One liner to find if first lines of two files are identical

Tags: unix, command-line-interface

Is there a simple use of head and cmp (or otherwise) to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the exit status of `diff` and `head` inside process substitution:

```
[kbrandt@localhost ~]$ echo arf > foo
[kbrandt@localhost ~]$ echo arf > foo1
[kbrandt@localhost ~]$ diff <(head -n1 foo) <(head -n1 foo1)
[kbrandt@localhost ~]$ echo $?
0
[kbrandt@localhost ~]$ echo foo > foo1
[kbrandt@localhost ~]$ diff <(head -n1 foo) <(head -n1 foo1)
1c1
< arf
---
> foo
[kbrandt@localhost ~]$ echo $?
1
[kbrandt@localhost ~]$
```

Diff compares the files, if the exit status is zero than the files match. Non-zero means they did not match or there was an error running diff which seems unlikely. `$?` is a shell variable that has the exit status of the previous command. You can redirect the output of diff by adding `> /dev/null` to the end of the diff command if you don't want to see it on the screen:

```
[kbrandt@localhost ~]$ diff <(head -n1 foo) <(head -n1 foo1) > /dev/null
[kbrandt@localhost ~]$ echo $?
1
```

Comment: Thank you Kyle, that's perfect. Process substitution was the concept I was missing.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it in Bash without using three calls to external utilities. It also works in POSIX shells that don't have process substitution:

```
read a<file1; read b<file2; [ "$a" = "$b" ]; echo $?
```

Here's another way using AWK:

```
awk 'FNR==1{a[NR]=$0; if (NR==2) exit a[1]!=a[2]; nextfile}' file1 file2
```

Note that AWK comparisons return 1 for true, so I'm using `!=` so the shell gets a 0 which it believes is true.

Comment: +1 -- Always like the bash only solutions :-)